# Adding a second scale above the figure in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

Is it possible to add a second scale above the figure on the horizontal axis for the same figure? I want to combine the date with the number of days since a reference date. The illustration should make clear what I mean:
[image: Applying two scales]

The code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,days,value
2015-01-01, 0, 3.2
2015-01-06, 5, 6.5
2015-01-15, 14, 6.8
2015-02-01, 31, 2.2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=2015-01-01,
    xmax=2015-02-01,
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day-\month-\year},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    grid=both,
    ymin=-1,ymax=10,
    xlabel={Date ($day-month-year$)},
    ylabel={Value},
]
\addplot table [x=date, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269222/how-to-access-internally-calculated-pgfplots-xtick-ytick/269529#269529, if only to avoid this approach.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I dont see how this relates to my question? Can you be more specific?

Comment: It is possible to access the tick values created and stored by pgfplots, but it is not by any means easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer by adding a second y axis with an invisible line; but maybe there is a more elegant way for doing this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,days,value
2015-01-01, 0, 3.2
2015-01-06, 5, 6.5
2015-01-15, 14, 6.8
2015-02-01, 31, 2.2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day-\month-\year},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    grid=both,
    ymin=-1,ymax=10,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Date ($day-month-year$)},
    ylabel={Value},
]
\addplot table [x=date, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    hide y axis,
    axis x line*=top,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Days since 01-01-2015},
]
\addplot [opacity=0] table [x=days, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the original specified xmin and xmax, you need to match it.

Comment: To get the correct range without explicit `xmin` and `xmax`, you can employ `enlargelimits=false` in the second axis.

Comment: To adjust the ticks you can use `xtick={3,8,...,28}`.

Comment: With the correct xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax values, you can lose the opacity=0 and not notice.

Comment: @ John, I get your point; I didn´t want to set the xmin/xmax in the first place but somehow it ended there which may have been a little bit sloppy.

Comment: @LucaD thnks for giving the solution. I changed it in the answer; Still I wonder if it is possible by not setting the xmin and xmax

Comment: You can avoid setting `xmin` and `xmax` in both `axis` environments if you add `enlargelimits=false` (or `enlarge x limits=false`).

Comment: Works! But I had to set `enlarge x limits=false` in both axis envs